# WordPress Jupiter theme GDPR configurations

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-font-api

I have this concern that my Jupiter theme is not GDPR ready. they have [this article](https://themes.artbees.net/docs/gdpr-wordpress-jupiter/) but it doesn't say anything about:

- Google Fonts
- ReCaptcha
- Youtube
- Google Maps

How can I make sure my website is GDPR ready?

Comment: you may check this link http://forums.artbees.net/t/loading-the-google-fonts-locally-instead-of-the-google-servers/13170

Comment: Thanks @TechnoDeviser It was useful :)

Answer (score 1):

The Google fonts part is explained at the bottom of the article.

The Google maps has nothing to do with Jupiter theme. They changed their policy and made it GDPR ready.

There is no recaptcha in the theme. In case you are using any third party plugin that uses recaptcha, you should ask the plugin authors.

Youtube also changed its policy and made it GDPR ready, but some still say that it's better to use socially hosted videos instead of Youtube. Jupiter theme video backgrounds and video player can handle both socially hosted videos (like youtube and vimeo) and locally hosted videos. So, you can choose between them.

Comment: "Youtube also changed its policy and made it GDPR ready."  I believe this is only true if you specify "enhanced privacy mode" when you configure your youtube embeds - and even then it sets an (empty) cookie.

Comment: This might no longer be true, due to the fallen Privacy Shield (Schrems 2). Data can no longer be transferred to the US, unless you can guarantee that the US government has no access (which is hard).